# SQL - Identify records in tables with Primary key mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle

```
TABLE A ( all fields are primary keys)
-----------------------------------------
SID  (INT)   
SDAY  (CHAR) 
DATETIME (DATETIME)
```

```
TABLE B ( all fields are primary keys- same as table A)
---------------------------------------------------------
SID
SDAY
DATETIME
```

I want to find 
Records in Table A

```
where A.SID = B.SID
AND A.SDAY = B.SDAY
AND A.DATETIME <> B.DATETIME
```

(i.e- I want to find records in table A matching corresponding columns in table B except datetime)

Direct INNER JOIN SQL is not giving me the results.  Any ideas?

**This also did not work**

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE  EXISTS (
SELECT 'X' FROM TABLE_B B
WHERE A.SID = B.SID
AND A.SDAY = B.SDAY 
AND A.DATETIME <> B.DATETIME)
```

Comment: What specifically did not work? It would help if you posted sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your question would be easier to read if you showed the table definitions like this:

-- I have two tables in Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A -- BTW: why the caps?
  ( SID INTEGER NOT NULL
  , SDAY CHAR NOT NULL
  , ZDATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL -- note: using a typename as an identier
                                -- will break things.
  , PRIMARY KEY (SID,SDAY,ZDATETIME)
  );

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B -- all (1)fields are primary keys
   ( SID SDAY DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   );
```

[maybe this should be a comment, but comments do not have the possibility for formatting]

(i.e- I want to find records in table A matching corresponding columns in table B

```
EXISTS
```

except datetime)

```
NOT EXISTS
```

Ok, Now for the solution:

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE_A A

WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_B B
    WHERE A.SID = B.SID
    AND A.SDAY = B.SDAY 
    )
AND NOT  EXISTS (
    SELECT 2 FROM TABLE_B B
    WHERE A.SID = B.SID
    AND A.SDAY = B.SDAY 
    AND A.ZDATETIME = B.ZDATETIME
    )
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it as an inner join instead of an exists, but I would expect yours to work.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON  A.SID = B.SID
AND A.SDAY = B.SDAY 
AND A.DATETIME <> B.DATETIME
```

If you're still not getting results maybe try posting some sample data for us to test with

---

Full test that you can run to show that the above join works:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table_a
(
    [SID] INT, 
    SDAY CHAR,
    [DATETIME] DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE #Table_b
(
    [SID] INT, 
    SDAY CHAR,
    [DATETIME] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Table_a
        ( SID, SDAY, DATETIME )
VALUES  ( 0, -- SID - int
          'A', -- SDAY - char
          '2012-12-27 23:00:01'  -- DATETIME - datetime
          )
INSERT INTO #Table_a
        ( SID, SDAY, DATETIME )
VALUES  ( 2, -- SID - int
          'B', -- SDAY - char
          '2012-12-27 23:00:01'  -- DATETIME - datetime
          )
INSERT INTO #Table_a
        ( SID, SDAY, DATETIME )
VALUES  ( 3, -- SID - int
          'C', -- SDAY - char
          '2012-12-27 23:00:01'  -- DATETIME - datetime
          )




INSERT INTO #Table_B
        ( SID, SDAY, DATETIME )
VALUES  ( 0, -- SID - int
          'A', -- SDAY - char
          '2012-12-27 3:00:01'  -- DATETIME - datetime
          )
INSERT INTO #Table_B
        ( SID, SDAY, DATETIME )
VALUES  ( 2, -- SID - int
          'B', -- SDAY - char
          '2012-12-27 3:00:01'  -- DATETIME - datetime
          )
INSERT INTO #Table_B
        ( SID, SDAY, DATETIME )
VALUES  ( 3, -- SID - int
          'C', -- SDAY - char
          '2012-12-27 23:00:01'  -- DATETIME - datetime
          )


SELECT A.* 
FROM #TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN #TABLE_B B
ON  A.SID = B.SID
AND A.SDAY = B.SDAY 
AND A.DATETIME <> B.DATETIME


DROP TABLE #Table_a
DROP TABLE #Table_b
```

Comment: That is invalid SQL for Oracle (or standard SQL)

Comment: Sorry, missed the Oracle tag. It should work in any version of MS SQL. Don't have Oracle handy to test it on. Which bit won't work in Oracle?

Comment: No, The OP is too lazy to give the proper table definitions. Everything goes, IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser it does say Oracle in the first line, it just wasn't tagged as such (has since been edited).

Comment: It does, but -even after my complaint- he managed to put his table definitions in vague ambigious text. And the MSql isms are just as annoying as any other vendor-specific extensions, IMnsvHO